# Closed and Exact $C^{1}$ $1$-Forms in $\mathbb{R}^{2}\setminus\left\{\mathbf{0}\right\}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, proof-explanation, differential-forms, line-integrals

> **(i)** Let $\omega$ be a closed $1$-form in $\mathbb{R}^{2}\setminus\left\{\mathbf{0}\right\}$ satisfying:
>       $$\int_{\gamma}\omega=0,$$
>       where $\gamma(t) = (\cos t,\sin t)$, $t \in [0, 2\pi]$. Show that $\omega$ is exact in $\mathbb{R}^{2}\setminus\left\{\mathbf{0}\right\}$.}
>
> **(ii)** Show that any closed $1$-form $\omega\in \mathbb{R}^{2}\setminus\left\{\mathbf{0}\right\}$ decomposes as:
>       $$\omega = \lambda\omega_{0} + \alpha,$$
>       where $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$, $\alpha$ is exact in $\mathbb{R}^{2}\setminus\left\{\mathbf{0}\right\}$, and $\omega_{0}$ is the (closed) ‘angle $1$-form’ in $\mathbb{R}^{2}\setminus\left\{\mathbf{0}\right\}$:
>       $$\omega_{0}=-\frac{y}{x^{2}+y^{2}}dx+\frac{x}{x^{2}+y^{2}}dy.$$

I am trying to work through this problem, but I think my (lack of) understanding of differential forms is holding me back.

So for the first question, I want to show that $\int_{\gamma}\omega=0$ for *any* closed curve $\gamma$ $\mathbb{R}^{2}\setminus\left\{\mathbf{0}\right\}$. Clearly this is true for any path that is homotopic to $S^{1}$. I feel that I should try to show that $\int_{\gamma}\omega=0$ has some uniform bound for any $\gamma$, but I am not sure how to construct it.

Also, I am confused how to actually look at this line integral and manipulate it.

The definition of line integral says that
$$\int_{\gamma}\omega=\int_{0}^{2\pi}(\omega(\gamma(t))[\gamma'(t)]dt$$
and I have seen another definition that says
$$\int_{\gamma}\omega=\int_{0}^{2\pi}(\omega(\gamma(t)), \gamma'(t))dt$$
 Here I am mostly confused how to manipulate $\omega$. In coordinates $\omega=\sum_{i}^{n}a_{i}(x)dx_{i}$ and $\omega$ is a map from $U\subset\mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow \Lambda^{1}$, where $\Lambda^{1}$ is the space of linear functionals $\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. So should I be looking at $\omega$ as a scalar? I do not understand how the decomposition of $\omega$ is used. My notes say nothing about each $a_{i}$ other than the fact that $\omega$ is $C^{k}$ if each $a_{i}$ is $C^{k}$

Given the two definitions of line-integral, I have either

$$\int_{\gamma}\omega=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\omega(\gamma(t)) [\gamma'(t)]dt = \int_{0}^{2\pi}\omega(\cos t, \sin t)[(-\sin t, \cos t)]dt=0$$

$$\int_{\gamma}\omega=\int_{0}^{2\pi}(\omega(\gamma(t)), \gamma'(t))dt = \int_{0}^{2\pi}(\omega(\cos t, \sin t), (-\sin t, \cos t))dt=0$$
But to me, neither of these integrands make sense.

The theorems we have to show exactness relate to being starshaped or simply connected, but clearly $\mathbb{R}^{2}\setminus\left\{\mathbf{0}\right\}$ is neither because of the hole at the origin.

We also know that since $\omega$ is closed, that
$$\frac{\partial a_{i}}{x_{j}}-\frac{\partial a_{j}}{x_{i}}=0,\ \  \forall i\neq j$$
but I am not sure how to relate this to the line integral.

I am unsure how to approach part **(ii)**.

We have covered a lot of Lebesgue integration, $L^{p}$ spaces, convergence theorems, etc. in my intro to analysis course, all of which I mostly understood well, but differential forms have been over my head. I appreciate any hints to help me understand the problems better.

Comment: To get more intuition for differential forms and integrating them, you might find some of my [lectures](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCp9W-et2Zbx7u5_VMiXGtPQ/videos) helpful. See MATH 3510, lectures 24-32 (Green's Theorem, surface integrals, and Stokes's Theorem come after those).

Comment: Thank you, so far the lectures are already very helpful!

Comment: You're very welcome. I just can't seriously give you hours of lecture/intuition here, but if you have specific questions for me after watching, by all means ask.